# Arithmetic overflow error for type int, value = 4957500001.400178

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, casting, logarithm, arithmetic-overflow

I know that similar questions have been asked again in the past, but I think my case is slightly different. I have a column which has Logarithmic values and I'm trying to invert them using the following formula:
`SELECT POWER(10,CAST(9.695262723 AS NUMERIC(30,15)))`

Let's say the value `9.695262723` is one of the values of that column.
When trying to run this query I get an `Arithmetic overflow error for type int, value = 4957500001.400178`.

On the other hand, the same query works fine for smaller values e.g. `SELECT POWER(10,CAST(8.662644523 AS NUMERIC(30,15)))`

How could I overcome that error and calculate the inverse values of the log10 entries I have? Just for information the greater value that exists in the table (in log10 scale) is `12.27256096`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem here is your first input parameter (`10`) which SQL server will, by default, treat as the datatype `int`.`int` has a maximum value of 2^31-1 (2,147,483,647), and the number 4,957,500,001 is far larger than this, so you need to use a `bigint`:

```
SELECT POWER(CONVERT(bigint,10),CONVERT(numeric(30,15),9.695262723));
```

*If you need to retain the decimal places, then use a `numeric` with a large enough scale and precision, instead of `bigint`.*